# Convert stored procedure to python pandas code?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

Column to be created rank using column author type.

Example:

| PMID | Rank |
| --- | --- |
| 200 | 3 |
| 201 | 0 |
| 200 | 0 |
| 202 | 0 |
| 200 | 2 |
| 201 | 1 |
| 200 | 1 |

Expected :

| PMID | Rank | Author_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | 3 | Last Author |
| 201 | 0 | First Author |
| 200 | 0 | First Author |
| 202 | 0 | First Author |
| 200 | 2 | Co Author |
| 201 | 1 | Last Author |
| 200 | 1 | Co Author |

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [datacleaning].[pub_set_authors]
AS
BEGIN
    WITH cte AS 
    (
        SELECT 
            *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [pub_id] ORDER BY [rank] DESC) AS rnk
        FROM 
            datacleaning.pubmed_details
    )
    UPDATE datacleaning.pubmed_details
    SET author_type = 'Last Author'
    WHERE row_id IN (SELECT row_id
                     FROM cte
                     WHERE rnk = 1)

    UPDATE datacleaning.pubmed_details
    SET author_type = 'First Author'
    WHERE rank = 0;

    UPDATE datacleaning.pubmed_details
    SET author_type = 'Co Author'
    WHERE author_type is NULL;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

This gets the results above; to replicate `row_number` `over` `partition` section in the sql code, you can combine `groupby` with `cumcount`. The next step uses `np.select`, similar to multiple case-when expressions:

```
(df.assign(row_number = df.groupby("PMID").Rank.cumcount(), 
           Author_type = lambda df: np.select([df.Rank == 0, 
                                               df.row_number.isin([0, 1]),  
                                               df.row_number > 1], 
                                              ['First Author', 
                                               'Last Author', 
                                               'Co Author'])
            )
  .drop(columns = 'row_number')
)



   PMID  Rank   Author_type
0   200     3   Last Author
1   201     0  First Author
2   200     0  First Author
3   202     0  First Author
4   200     2     Co Author
5   201     1   Last Author
6   200     1     Co Author
```